# How to add elements to container having only iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have an empty container with reserved memory. My function (algorithm) doesn't take a container, only the iterator to begin of it. How to add elements to container in this function? I need allocate memory and call the constructor, but how to call the constructor in place referenced by iterator?

Comment: Please explain why you only have an iterator. Most iterators don't let you alter the container; you have to have access to the container for that. BTW, the difference between an iterator and a const iterator is whether you can alter the element, not the container.

Comment: Also, **please mark correct answers to your questions.**

Comment: I'm asking why it's a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally by using something like an `std::inserter_iterator`. This, however, doesn't normally eliminate the requirement for a pointer or reference to the container -- it just stores that reference inside the iterator itself.

If you have a pre-set iterator type, this does no good. If you have something like a normal algorithm that just needs to take and use something that uses an iterator interface to insert into the collection, it works beautifully.

Comment: std::inserter_iterator must take a container. But it is not taken by the algorithm

Comment: You feed the container to the `inserter_iterator` when you create the iterator, which is before your function gets called. After that, you just need the iterator.

Comment: So, I have added only one element to the container with insert_iterator. And then an error appeared. Where insert_iterator should point, to begin or to end? And should I increment it?

Comment: @user1290126: Normally you use the container's `back_insert_iterator()` or `front_insert_iterator()` (for a couple of examples) to get an insert_iterator to that container.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has the concept of an insert_iterator, which is what I assume you're after?

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int my_array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::vector<int> my_vector;

    std::copy( std::begin( my_array ),
               std::end( my_array ),
               std::back_inserter( my_vector ) );
}
```

Comment: I can't use the container! I have only iterator.

Comment: @user1290126: look better. `std::copy` does not know anything about `my_vector`, it is just passed an iterator, and yet it will still copy into the vector, expanding it as it goes. This is the magic behing an `Output Iterator`. Here `std::back_insert(my_vector)` creates an iterator that when written to appends to the vector.

Comment: @user1290126 What kind of iterator do you have?   an insert_iterator is capable of inserting data because it knows about the container, however if all you've got is an ordinary forward_iterator, then the question you're asking is more akin to "How do i resize an array using only a pointer to an element" - to which the answer is simply "you can't" - Usually, the onus is on the caller of the function to decide which kind of iterator to use, and whether that iterator is capable of modifying the container.

Comment: Is the only way to pass to the function an insert iterator instead traverse iterator?

Comment: Short of passing in a container reference, yes. Traversal iterators are only for *traversal,* not *modification* of a container. Note that many iterators become invalid when a container is modified!

Answer (score 3):

You cant change container, having only traverse iterator; however, you can use insert iterator instead.

Edited:
If you reserve memory you must know how many elements it will contain. Then you can add empty elements before passing into the function instead and fill them using the iterator, incrementing it. After that you can return this iterator and it will point to the position where usefull data end.

Comment: not good idea, because I know possible maximum number of elements, and if the container is associative, such empty elements may take place not at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert an element into a container without a reference/pointer to that container.

You can, however, overwrite an element (assuming you don't have a `const_iterator`).  Something like:

```
*it = T(params);
```

where `T` is the type in question.